# How to make the stick figure I made move using inputs?

Tags: java

Ignore the near end where the direction and player stances are mentioned. I know I have to repaint the stick figure but I don't know how, someone help please. I am currently working on a combat system with for a game my friends and I are making, so I need some help figuring out how to move the user's character around

```
package CombatSystem;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Combat extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    private boolean play = false;

    private int user_health = 3;
    private int boss_health = 3;

    private int playerPosX = 100;
    private int playerPosY = 100;

    private int player_stance = 0;

    private int direction = 0;

    //1 = Attack, 2 = Defense
    Timer mainTimer;


    public Combat() {

        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);
        mainTimer = new Timer(10, this);
        mainTimer.start();
    }


    public void paint(Graphics x) {
        //Background
        super.paint(x);
        x.setColor(Color.black);
        x.fillRect(1,1,886,662);

        //Floor
        x.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        x.fillRect(1, 550, 886, 662);

        //User
        x.setColor(Color.white);
        //Head
        x.drawOval(90, 60, 20, 20);
        //Body
        x.drawLine(100, 80, 100, 110);
        //Arms
        x.drawLine(100, 90, 80, 105);
        x.drawLine(100, 90, 120, 105);
        //Legs
        x.drawLine(100, 110, 85, 135);
        x.drawLine(100, 110, 115, 135);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        repaint();
    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {    
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            playerPosX += 20;
            }
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            playerPosX -= 20;
            }

    }   
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_1) {
            direction = 1;

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                player_stance = 1;
                //Attack Stance
            }
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                player_stance = 2;
                //Defense Stance
            }
        }
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_2) {
            direction = 2;

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                player_stance = 1;
                //Attack Stance
            }
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                player_stance = 2;
                //Defense Stance
            }
        }
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_3) {
            direction = 3;

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                player_stance = 1;
                //Attack Stance
            }
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                player_stance = 2;
                //Defense Stance
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


    }

}
```

Comment: Well, you're going to need to adjust the position of your finger's drawing location.  A "simple" solution might be to translate the `Graphics` context to the position you want the figure drawn and always draw the figure starting at `0x0`.  I'd also encourage you to use `paintComponent` over `paint` ;)

Comment: I can't just look at your code and see a problem.  I need a [mre] so I can take the code, put it in my Eclipse, compile it, run it, and try different things.  Won't you help us help you?

Comment: @Intisaurus, i think it is good time to start OOP.